# Sampling from a distribution: Where to find the basics

Tags: sampling, references

Part of my project requires that I do some sampling and although I can find some answers, i find my questions to be rather basic ( like sampling from a truncated normal or sampling from a marginal distribution). I could find answers here, but I feel that it should be easy to find an answer to such questions in a book, but it seems that there is no such thing. I can't find any theory properly written!

My question is, can I find such a book/ pdf lecture, and if yes, where :)?

Edit: Some context to better understand my question:

A couple days ago, I wondered how to sample from a marginal distribution 
$f_X(x) = \int f(x|y) f(y) dy$, I asked around, got an answer, but they weren't able to explain why it worked ( sample from y plug y in the conditional, keep the x) , and it sort of makes sense but i can't justify it, and it happened to me before that when it comes to sampling, no one can give much more than recipes. And i would like to know where i can find how to "prove" it.

Thank you :)

Comment: It's not really clear to me what specifically you are interested in. Are you interested in [inverse transform sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/307686/1352)? Or in software implementations? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Ok, well, couple days ago, I wondered how to sample from a marginal distribution $f_X(x) = \int f(x|y)f(y)dy$, I asked around, got an answer, but they weren't able to explain why it worked ( sample from y plug y in the conditional, keep the x) , and it sort of makes sense but i can't justify it, and it happened to me before that when it comes to sampling, no one can give much more than recipes. And i would like to know where i can find how to "prove" it. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks! Could you please edit that information into the question? That would make it a lot easier to answer. (And comments are ephemeral.)

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: A good book is "Simulation" from Sheldon Ross. Chapters 3, 4 and 5 explain all about generating random numbers.

Comment: Linked: but unanswered... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700315/do-sample-from-and-insert-parameter-commute

Comment: I think my answer here will help u to get the idea https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233581/mc-sampling-from-a-posterior-distribution/233750#233750